# How to declare new map() by using ref in setup hook - vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am migrating my vue 2 application into vue 3. While exploring composition api, i came to know about ref function in setup hook which is replacing data function of option api.

**In vue 2:**

```
data() {
  return {
   cntmap: new Map()
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to initialize it in ref function of setup hook. I have started learning vue 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const mapList = ref(new Map())
    
    mapList.value.set('a', 1);
    mapList.value.set('b', 2);
    mapList.value.set('c', 3);

    return { mapList }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <li v-for="item in mapList" :key="item">
    {{ item }}
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Since it's not reassigned, it makes more sense for it to be `reactive`.